# Make the font size of label in another form smaller

Tags: vb.net, winforms, font-size

I am using two `forms`,when i click on the button in first `form` `FormSales`,I want to display the `text` "Non-Inventory Price" with reduced `fontsize` on the `label` of `publicform` `FormNumberpad`.My code is,

```
Private Sub btnItemNonTaxable_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) _
                                    Handles btnItemNonTaxable.Click
    chktax1.Checked = False
    _AmountTitle = "Non Inventory Taxable Price"
    Dim fnt as Font
    fnt = FormNumberPad.lblTitle.Font
    FormNumberPad.lblTitle.Font = New Font(fnt.Name, 12, FontStyle.Bold)
    Dim numberpad As New FormNumberPad
    numberpad.ShowDialog()

    ..............
    ..............
End Sub
```

The font size does not get decreased, how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here

```
Dim numberpad As New FormNumberPad
numberpad.ShowDialog()
```

you are creating a new instance of FormNumberPad and this instance is shown with ShowDialog().
ShowDialog is modal, meaning that it doesn't return till you close the form shown.
At that point your label (still existing in memory) is hidden and you don't see any change.

You could try to change the label before displaying the dialog, but on the current instance of the form (numberpad) not on the FormNumberPad that is the class definition of the dialog.

```
Dim numberpad As New FormNumberPad
fnt = numberpad .lblTitle.Font
numberpad.lblTitle.Font = New Font(fnt.Name, 12, FontStyle.Bold)
numberpad.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: If you want to change the font at runtime this is the best way.

Answer (score 1):

It is because you are using 'New' FormNumberPad, change that line and below with `FormNumberPad.ShowDialog()`